# Compile gpio-mockup in 5.4

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've checked out kernel 5.4 source and tried to compile [`gpio-mockup.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpio/gpio-mockup.c?h=v5.4) by running `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules` the build succeeds but there is no `gpio-mockup.ko`. I think this means that I need to provide some configuration value but I don't know how and I don't know where. Regardless, can anyone help me to build the gpio-mockup kernel module?

Comment: Just do it the way I usually do. `mkdir /tmp/gpio-mockup; cp $KSRC/drivers/gpio/gpio-mockup.c $KSRC/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.h /tmp/gpio-mockup; echo "obj-m += gpio-mockup.o" > Makefile; cd /tmp/gpio-mockup; make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules`. Note, it will have no ability to produce simulated IRQs. To make it happen you have to recompile entire kernel.

Comment: I don't think I need the simulated IRQs (at least not now). Though let's say I did. Are there any specific kconfig commands I need in order to make it build?

Comment: Nope, above is a full command line I guess. If compilation goes, then you should get a file.

Comment: It almost worked 3 errors `ERROR: "irq_sim_fire" [/tmp/tmp.rrJ03lwip9/gpio-mockup.ko] undefined!`, `ERROR: "devm_irq_sim_init" [/tmp/tmp.rrJ03lwip9/gpio-mockup.ko] undefined!`, `ERROR: "irq_sim_irqnum" [/tmp/tmp.rrJ03lwip9/gpio-mockup.ko] undefined!`. I assume these are the IRQ things you mentioned? I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have tried myself and see the same. Alas, you have to recompile entire kernel. IRQ simulation is a hard dependency here. Of course you may try to produce a patch that makes it optional.

Comment: I am going to compile my own kernel. I'm enabling `Debug GPIO calls` and `GPIO Testing Driver` in Kernel Configuration. Is this right or should I try something else?

Comment: Okay built with `Debug GPIO calls` and `GPIO Testing Driver` it made the `gpio-mockup.o` file but that did not turn into a `gpio-mockup.ko` file. I am stumped.

Comment: After you got your *.config* (dotconfig file) run `make nconfig` and go thru menus to enable it. Then build your kernel as usual.

Answer (score 2):

Because the gpio-mockup module depends on some GPL symbols in the kernel it needs to be built with the kernel. This means you must build a whole new kernel.

```sh
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git linux
cd linux
git checkout v5.4
cp /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/.config ./
yes '' | make oldconfig
echo "CONFIG_GPIO_MOCKUP=m" >> .config
make -j $(nproc) deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-gpio-mockup
```

This will produce Debian packages that can then be used to install a new kernel that will include the gpio-mockup kernel module.

***NOTE:*** This is a vanilla kernel which may or may not have kernel modules your distribution usually provides (like ZFS on Ubuntu). Other steps may be necessary to get a custom kernel like your distribution provides.

Comment: Instead of using _yes_, you may run _make olddefconfig_.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable CONFIG_IRQ_SIM=y, since gpio-mockup.ko is depended irq_sim.

[please look at this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzV8W.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).